# Share intent only works with some apps

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a share button that will share an Image with some extra caption text to social media.
The code I'm using now works fine with some apps, but doesn't work in other apps.
Here's the code:

```
  String message = "hello world";

            Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getActivity().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.loremipsum2);
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            intent.setType("image/jpeg");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            startActivity(intent);
```

I've been searching for hours what the problem may be, but none of the solutions have worked for me so far.

**Apps where it does work:**

-Telegram

-Drive

-Reddit

**Apps where it doesn't work:**

-WhatsApp

-Gmail

**Error when sharing to Gmail:**

```
Gmail:Can't find android resource
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: No package found for authority: android.resource://com.test.testApp/2131820547
```

**Error when sharing to whatsapp**

```
Access denied finding property "ro.vendor.scroll.preobtain.enable"
```

I'm going crazy onto this one, I need it to work and can obviously be achieved, as many apps can share images to whatsapp.
Any ideas on how to solve it? you're welcome! :)

Answer (score 1):

`EXTRA_STREAM` is [documented](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#EXTRA_STREAM) to take a `content:` `Uri`. That is not what you are using. Few developers know of the `android.resource` scheme. Fewer still will have code that handles it when an app uses one unexpectedly in `EXTRA_STREAM`.

For better compatibility, use a `ContentProvider` and a `content:` `Uri` that points to it. For example, you could share a file with `FileProvider`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so finally, after researching a lot, trust me, a lot, I've finally found an answer to my question, so I'm posting it here as it seems like a pretty basic feature to have in an app.

The solution is, as CommonsWare said, using a fileProvider.
I also used a class I found on github to manage cache usage , it is linked [here](https://gist.github.com/nikartm/79932c0a4f0a644f7ce020143146db98), as `FileProvider` may not use resource URIs

The idea is, store the image in cache, then call `Cache` class to provide a valid URI to the image in cache, and then use that URI for the `EXTRA_STREAM`

Follow this guide to solve the issue: (it works in all apps I've tried so far. It should also work for other File types with some little modifications.)

**SOLUTION**

**1-Create the class that handles cache. Here's code:**

```
public class Cache {

    public static final String TAG = Cache.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final String CHILD_DIR = "images";
    private static final String TEMP_FILE_NAME = "img";
    private static final String FILE_EXTENSION = ".png";
    private Context context;

    private static final int COMPRESS_QUALITY = 100;


    public Cache(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    /**
     * Save image to the App cache
     * @param bitmap to save to the cache
     * @param name file name in the cache.
     * If name is null file will be named by default {@link #TEMP_FILE_NAME}
     * @return file dir when file was saved
     */
    public File saveImgToCache(Bitmap bitmap, @Nullable String name) {
        File cachePath = null;
        String fileName = TEMP_FILE_NAME;
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
            fileName = name;
        }
        try {
            cachePath = new File(context.getCacheDir(), CHILD_DIR);
            cachePath.mkdirs();

            FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(cachePath + "/" + fileName + FILE_EXTENSION);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, COMPRESS_QUALITY, stream);
            stream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "saveImgToCache error: " + bitmap, e);
        }
        return cachePath;
    }

    /**
     * Save an image to the App cache dir and return it {@link Uri}
     * @param bitmap to save to the cache
     */
    public Uri saveToCacheAndGetUri(Bitmap bitmap) {
        return saveToCacheAndGetUri(bitmap, null);
    }

    /**
     * Save an image to the App cache dir and return it {@link Uri}
     * @param bitmap to save to the cache
     * @param name file name in the cache.
     * If name is null file will be named by default {@link #TEMP_FILE_NAME}
     */
    public Uri saveToCacheAndGetUri(Bitmap bitmap, @Nullable String name) {
        File file = saveImgToCache(bitmap, name);
        return getImageUri(file, name);
    }

    /**
     * Get a file {@link Uri}
     * @param name of the file
     * @return file Uri in the App cache or null if file wasn't found
     */
    @Nullable public Uri getUriByFileName(String name) {
        Context context = this.context;
        String fileName;
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
            fileName = name;
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        File imagePath = new File(context.getCacheDir(), CHILD_DIR);
        File newFile = new File(imagePath, fileName + FILE_EXTENSION);
        return FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getPackageName() + ".provider", newFile);
    }

    // Get an image Uri by name without extension from a file dir
    private Uri getImageUri(File fileDir, @Nullable String name) {
        Context context = this.context;
        String fileName = TEMP_FILE_NAME;
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
            fileName = name;
        }
        File newFile = new File(fileDir, fileName + FILE_EXTENSION);
        return FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getPackageName() + ".provider", newFile);
    }

    /**
     * Get Uri type by {@link Uri}
     */
    public String getContentType(Uri uri) {
        return this.context.getContentResolver().getType(uri);
    }

}
```

I've done little to none modification to this class, the author is Ivan V on 12.05.2019. (Github)

This class uses a `FileProvider` internally. `FileProvider` will allow other apps to access our app files.
To configure file providers, we have to do some modification in `AndroidManifest.xml`

**2 - Inside the `<application>` tag, place the following `FileProvider` config:**

```
<provider
                android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
                android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
                android:grantUriPermissions="true"
                android:exported="false"
                tools:replace="android:authorities">
            <meta-data
                    android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                    android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
```

And create `file_paths.xml` in `/res/xml` (if the xml folder doesn't exist, create it to) with the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <files-path name="file_path" path="."/>
    <external-files-path name="external_path" path="/" />
</paths>
```

**3 - Create the sharing method in your activity**

```
public void shareImage(){
Cache cache = new Cache(getActivity());
                cache.saveImgToCache(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.raw.loremipsum),"testImg");
                Uri sendUri =  cache.getUriByFileName("testImg");

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "whatsAppMessage");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, sendUri);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                startActivity(intent);
}
```

Just change all image names etc and you are ready to go!!
I hope i was helpful :)